# Error 00904 Invalid Identifier from WHERE clause in PLSQL Select Statement Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to construct a SELECT statement and execute it but I keep having this error. My statement goes something like this:

```
DECLARE
   SOMESTRING varchar2(20);
BEGIN
   SOMESTRING := 'Test_Col';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM TBL_TEST WHERE column = ' || SOMESTRING;
```

I get a "00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier". I know it must be a syntax error but I am not sure what should be written as I am new to PL/SQL.

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT col FROM TBL_TEST WHERE aColumn = '''Literal_String''' into TEST_VALUE;
```

It prints out the value correctly but when I do:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT col FROM TBL_TEST WHERE aColumn = :SOMESTRING' INTO TEST_VALUE USING SOMESTRING;
```

It says no data. Yes I have declared all necessary variables.

EDIT 2:

In my application, I assigned SOMESTRING to:

```
SOMESTRING := CONCAT('A', SUBSTR(a_table_name, 2));
```

In this case, how do I do a triple quote in this case? Because it will just become a literal string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
DECLARE
   SOMESTRING varchar2(20);
BEGIN
   SOMESTRING := 'Test_Col';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT col1 FROM TBL_TEST WHERE column = :SOMESTRING' using SOMESTRING;
END;
```

Edit:

```
DECLARE
   SOMESTRING varchar2(20);
   abv   varchar2(20); -- Variable to hold your result
BEGIN
   SOMESTRING := 'Test_Col';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[SELECT 'A' FROM DUAL WHERE 'Test_Col' = :SOMESTRING]' into abv using SOMESTRING ;

   dbms_output.put_line(abv); -- Print your result.
END;
```

Explaination:

The below block shows what values you are trying to pass.
If you see the first statement, you will see that you are passing string literal with `'` but in second statement when you pass it as bind varaible you pass it without `'`. Hence you get no data.

```
declare
  v   varchar2(1000);
  SOMESTRING varchar2(20);
begin 

v:= 'SELECT col FROM TBL_TEST WHERE aColumn = ''literal_string''';
dbms_output.put_line (v);

SOMESTRING := 'Test_Col';
dbms_output.put_line (SOMESTRING);
v:='SELECT col FROM TBL_TEST WHERE aColumn = :SOMESTRING';
dbms_output.put_line (v);

end;
```

Output:

```
SELECT col FROM TBL_TEST WHERE aColumn = 'literal_string'
SELECT col FROM TBL_TEST WHERE aColumn = :SOMESTRING

SELECT col FROM TBL_TEST WHERE aColumn = 'literal_string'
Test_Col
SELECT col FROM TBL_TEST WHERE aColumn = :SOMESTRING
```

Remedy:

```
while assiging `SOMESTRING` do it as :

SOMESTRING := '''Test_Col''';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. It works. How about if I want to put the result of that select statement into a declared integer variable?

Comment: @loveprogramming Then you need to use `INTO` clause to hold your result of the query. See my edit,

Comment: Thanks. Anyways for some reason I am not getting any data back. It says no data was found, but Im pretty sure there's data in it.

Comment: @loveprogramming Check your query standalone running in `SQL`.. Check if it returns rows. Also note that you need either several variables to hold result if your query returns multiple rows or a variable of rowtype of your table.

Comment: When I put a literal string in place of :SOMETHING, it returns value of 'A' in your select statement. However when I changed it back, it said no data.

Comment: @loveprogramming Edit your question and show what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Pls see my updated post

Comment: assign it like `SOMESTRING := '''SOMESTRING '''`

Comment: I cant do that because I have to assigned a concatenation of two strings using Concat function to the variable SOMESTRING as shown in my updated post

Comment: @loveprogramming.. Ofcourse you can.. What i posted is next statement after  your concatenation.

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry it still doesnt work for me. I even tried assigning `SOMESTRING := '''LITERAL_STRING'''`, but it still returned no data. The only way I could make it return data is when I followed the first statement `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT col FROM TBL_TEST WHERE aColumn = '''Literal_String''' into TEST_VALUE;`

Comment: @loveprogramming Go with that. Both are nearly same